# How to get the error message from a failed transaction with web3?

Tags: web3.py, raw-transaction, receipts, vyper, failed-transaction

My smart contract has the following piece of code:

```
# check if the election has begun. begin and end time must be in the future and in unix timestamp
assert block.timestamp < self.elections[_election_id].begin_unix_timestamp, "The election has already started"
```

On the block explorer (https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xef2d5fe12514ecfe582e191b97316a4c99f5b24c4213ea0a1940dde179ec8f1e) I can see that the transaction has failed with the error message:

> Status: Fail with error 'The election has already started'

How can I access this error message using web3? All I have access to is the status code in the transaction receipt, but not the error message:

```
signed_transaction = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=goerli_account_private_key)
sent_raw_transaction = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(sent_raw_transaction)
print(receipt.status)
# print(some_transaction_object.fail_message) # I'm looking for something like this
```

Answer (score 0):

This works using a w3 connection to infura:

```
# fetch a reverted transaction:
tx = w3.eth.get_transaction('0xdc9978af3e19475ee019cc21fd8513db74a98539ab373a9eb768423096ee2...')
# build a new transaction to replay:
replay_tx = {
    'to': tx['to'],
    'from': tx['from'],
    'value': tx['value'],
    'data': tx['input'],
}

# replay the transaction locally:
try:
    w3.eth.call(replay_tx, tx.blockNumber - 1)
except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

Comment: so, `e` contains the error message that I can see on the block explorer?